# _Alignas(N), [[gnu::aligned(N)]], and __attribute__((aligned(N))) position in declarations

Tags: c, gcc, memory-alignment

For the following union (without AAA or BBB):

```
union AAA bpf_attr {
        struct {    /* Used by BPF_MAP_CREATE */
                uint32_t    map_type;
                uint32_t    key_size;    /* size of key in bytes */
                uint32_t    value_size;  /* size of value in bytes */
                uint32_t    max_entries; /* maximum number of entries
                                            in a map */
        };

        struct {    /* Used by BPF_MAP_*_ELEM and BPF_MAP_GET_NEXT_KEY commands */
                uint32_t            map_fd;
                uint64_t alignas(8) key;
                union {
                        uint64_t alignas(8) value;
                        uint64_t alignas(8) next_key;
                };
                uint64_t            flags;
        };

        struct {    /* Used by BPF_PROG_LOAD */
                uint32_t            prog_type;
                uint32_t            insn_cnt;
                uint64_t alignas(8) insns;     /* 'const struct bpf_insn *' */
                uint64_t alignas(8) license;   /* 'const char *' */
                uint32_t            log_level; /* verbosity level of verifier */
                uint32_t            log_size;  /* size of user buffer */
                uint64_t alignas(8) log_buf;   /* user supplied 'char *'
                                                  buffer */
                uint32_t            kern_version;
                                               /* checked when prog_type=kprobe
                                                  (since Linux 4.1) */
        };
} BBB;
```

Is there any difference if I put `_Alignas(8)` at `AAA` or `BBB` (or any other position if valid)?  The standard doesn't seem to specify.  Is there any difference between any of the former or doing the same with `[[gnu::aligned(8)]]`?  GCC does specify some difference, but I don't understand the text:

> Where attribute specifiers follow the closing brace, they are
> considered to relate to the structure, union or enumerated type
> defined, *not to any enclosing declaration the type specifier appears
> in*, and the type defined is not complete until after the attribute
> specifiers.

**EDIT:**

After some tests, it seems that (but am not sure at all):

```
union alignas(N) u {
        ...
} v;
```

The above is not legal.

---

```
union u {
        ...
} alignas(N) v;
```

The above is only legal because there's a variable declaration.  It should be equivalent to:

```
union u {
        ...
};
union u alignas(N) v;
```

---

```
union [[gnu::aligned(8)]] u {
        ...
};
```

The above seems to be legal, without the need of a variable declaration.

---

```
union u {
        ...
} [[gnu::aligned(8)]] v;
```

The above seems to be ignored (with a warning), but I don't understand why;  the text says that it's allowed, even if it's not the preferred version.

---

Yet another weird thing:
The last form doesn't trigger a warning if instead of C2x syntax you use `__attribute__((aligned(8)))`, which by the way is the form that Linux uses in its source code.

I could test more combinations, but it's an exponential thing, and a theoretical answer seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the theoretical answer is according to the standard and the GNU documentation, as they're not very detailed, but here's an extensive experimental answer.

For my experiment I wrote the following file:

`align.c`:

```
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} s_, s__;

__attribute__((aligned(16))) struct t {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} t_, t__;

alignas(16) struct tt {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} tt_, tt__;

[[gnu::aligned(16)]] struct ttt {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} ttt_, ttt__;

struct __attribute__((aligned(16))) u {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} u_, u__;
/*  error: expected ‘{’ before ‘_Alignas’
struct alignas(16) uu {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} uu_, uu__;
*/
struct [[gnu::aligned(16)]] uuu {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} uuu_, uuu__;
/*  error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
struct v __attribute__((aligned(16))) {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} v_, v_;
*/
/*  error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
struct vv alignas(16) {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} vv_, vv__;
*/
//  warning: ignoring attributes applied to ‘struct vvv’ after definition [-Wattributes]
/*  error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
struct vvv [[gnu::aligned(16)]] {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} vvv_, vvv__;
*/
struct w {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} __attribute__((aligned(16))) w_, w__;

struct ww {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} alignas(16) ww_, ww__;
//  warning: ignoring attributes applied to ‘struct www’ after definition [-Wattributes]
struct www {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} [[gnu::aligned(16)]] www_, www__;

struct x {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} x_ __attribute__((aligned(16))), x__;
/*  error: expected ‘;’ before ‘_Alignas’
struct xx {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} xx_ alignas(16), xx__;
*/
struct xxx {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} xxx_ [[gnu::aligned(16)]], xxx__;

struct y {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} y_, __attribute__((aligned(16))) y__;
/*  error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘_Alignas’
struct yy {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} yy_, alignas(16) yy__;
*/
/*  error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
struct yyy {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} yyy_, [[gnu::aligned(16)]] yyy__;
*/
struct z {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} z_, z__ __attribute__((aligned(16)));
/*  error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_Alignas’
struct zz {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} zz_, zz__ alignas(16);
*/
struct zzz {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} zzz_, zzz__ [[gnu::aligned(16)]];


int main(void)
{
    printf("s:   %2zu;  s_:   %2zu; s__:     %2zu\n\n", alignof(struct s), alignof(s_), alignof(s__));
    printf("t:   %2zu;  t_:   %2zu; t__:     %2zu\n", alignof(struct t), alignof(t_), alignof(t__));
    printf("tt:  %2zu;  tt_:  %2zu; tt__:    %2zu\n", alignof(struct tt), alignof(tt_), alignof(tt__));
    printf("ttt: %2zu;  ttt_: %2zu; ttt__:   %2zu\n\n", alignof(struct ttt), alignof(ttt_), alignof(ttt__));
    printf("u:   %2zu;  u_:   %2zu; u__:     %2zu\n", alignof(struct u), alignof(u_), alignof(u__));
    puts("uu:   -");//  printf("uu:  %2zu;  uu_:  %2zu; uu__:    %2zu\n", alignof(struct uu), alignof(uu_), alignof(uu__));
    printf("uuu: %2zu;  uuu_: %2zu; uuu__:   %2zu\n\n", alignof(struct uuu), alignof(uuu_), alignof(uuu__));
    puts("v:    -");//  printf("v:   %2zu;  v_:   %2zu; v__:     %2zu\n", alignof(struct v), alignof(v_), alignof(v__));
    puts("vv:   -");//  printf("vv:  %2zu;  vv_:  %2zu; vv__:    %2zu\n", alignof(struct vv), alignof(vv_), alignof(vv__));
    puts("vvv:  -\n");//    printf("vvv: %2zu;  vvv_: %2zu; vvv__:   %2zu\n", alignof(struct vvv), alignof(vvv_), alignof(vvv__));
    printf("w:   %2zu;  w_:   %2zu; w__:     %2zu\n", alignof(struct w), alignof(w_), alignof(w__));
    printf("ww:  %2zu;  ww_:  %2zu; ww__:    %2zu\n", alignof(struct ww), alignof(ww_), alignof(ww__));
    printf("www: %2zu;  www_: %2zu; www__:   %2zu\n\n", alignof(struct www), alignof(www_), alignof(www__));
    printf("x:   %2zu;  x_:   %2zu; x__:     %2zu\n", alignof(struct x), alignof(x_), alignof(x__));
    puts("xx:   -");//  printf("xx:  %2zu;  xx_:  %2zu; xx__:    %2zu\n", alignof(struct xx), alignof(xx_), alignof(xx__));
    printf("xxx: %2zu;  xxx_: %2zu; xxx__:   %2zu\n\n", alignof(struct xxx), alignof(xxx_), alignof(xxx__));
    printf("y:   %2zu;  y_:   %2zu; y__:     %2zu\n", alignof(struct y), alignof(y_), alignof(y__));
    puts("yy:   -");//  printf("yy:  %2zu;  yy_:  %2zu; yy__:    %2zu\n", alignof(struct yy), alignof(yy_), alignof(yy__));
    puts("yyy:  -\n");//    printf("yyy: %2zu;  yyy_: %2zu; yyy__:   %2zu\n\n", alignof(struct yyy), alignof(yyy_), alignof(yyy__));
    printf("z:   %2zu;  z_:   %2zu; z__:     %2zu\n", alignof(struct z), alignof(z_), alignof(z__));
    puts("zz:   -");//  printf("zz:  %2zu;  zz_:  %2zu; zz__:    %2zu\n", alignof(struct zz), alignof(zz_), alignof(zz__));
    printf("zzz: %2zu;  zzz_: %2zu; zzz__:   %2zu\n", alignof(struct zzz), alignof(zzz_), alignof(zzz__));

    return 0;
}
```

`cc -Wall -Wextra align.c -o align` gives the warnings and errors I commented above.  I had to comment out some code to make it compile.

```
$ ./align
s:    8;    s_:    8;   s__:      8

t:    8;    t_:   16;   t__:     16
tt:   8;    tt_:  16;   tt__:    16
ttt:  8;    ttt_: 16;   ttt__:   16

u:   16;    u_:   16;   u__:     16
uu:   -
uuu: 16;    uuu_: 16;   uuu__:   16

v:    -
vv:   -
vvv:  -

w:   16;    w_:   16;   w__:     16
ww:   8;    ww_:  16;   ww__:    16
www:  8;    www_: 16;   www__:   16

x:    8;    x_:   16;   x__:      8
xx:   -
xxx:  8;    xxx_: 16;   xxx__:    8

y:    8;    y_:    8;   y__:     16
yy:   -
yyy:  -

z:    8;    z_:    8;   z__:     16
zz:   -
zzz:  8;    zzz_:  8;   zzz__:   16
```

Conclusion:

If the alignment attribute goes before the `struct` keyword, it applies to any variables declared, but not to the type itself.

If the attribute goes between the `struct` keyword and the `struct` tag, it applies to both the type and any variables declared.  This is invalid for C11 `alignas()`, which doesn't compile.

The attribute can't go just before `{`.

If the attribute goes just after the `}`, if works as if if were before the `struct` keyword (applies only to any variables declared), EXCEPT for old GNU syntax, which applies to the type itself too.

If the attribute goes after a declared variable, it applies to it only.  This is invalid for C11 `alignas()`, which doesn't compile.

If the attribute goes before one declared variable that is not the first one (there is at least a comma between `}`, and the attribute), it applies to the variable next to it only.  This is only valid for old GNU syntax; others don't compile.