# __attribute__((packed)) and [[gnu::packed]] position in declarations

Tags: c, gcc, struct, attributes

Where should the `packed` attribute be placed in declarations?
Is there any difference between usage of the C2x (C++-style) and the old GNU attribute?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271825/alignasn-gnualignedn-and-attribute-alignedn-position-in-de/67382793#67382793

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the GCC documentation isn't very clear, I developed the following test program for an experimental answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} s_, s__;

// warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
__attribute__((packed)) struct t {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} t_, t__;

// warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
[[gnu::packed]] struct ttt {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} ttt_, ttt__;

struct __attribute__((packed)) u {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} u_, u__;

struct [[gnu::packed]] uuu {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} uuu_, uuu__;

// error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
/*
struct v __attribute__((packed)) {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} v_, v_;
*/

// error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
/*
struct vvv [[gnu::packed]] {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} vvv_, vvv__;
*/

struct w {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} __attribute__((packed)) w_, w__;

// warning: 'packed' attribute ignored for type 'struct www' [-Wattributes]
struct www {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} [[gnu::packed]] www_, www__;

// warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
struct x {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} x_ __attribute__((packed)), x__;

// warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
struct xxx {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} xxx_ [[gnu::packed]], xxx__;

// warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
struct y {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} y_, __attribute__((packed)) y__;

// error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
/*
struct yyy {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} yyy_, [[gnu::packed]] yyy__;
*/

// warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
struct z {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} z_, z__ __attribute__((packed));

// warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
struct zzz {
    char a;
    long b;
    char c;
} zzz_, zzz__ [[gnu::packed]];


int main(void)
{
    printf("s:   %2zu;  s_:   %2zu; s__:     %2zu\n\n", sizeof(struct s), sizeof(s_), sizeof(s__));
    printf("t:   %2zu;  t_:   %2zu; t__:     %2zu\n", sizeof(struct t), sizeof(t_), sizeof(t__));
    printf("ttt: %2zu;  ttt_: %2zu; ttt__:   %2zu\n\n", sizeof(struct ttt), sizeof(ttt_), sizeof(ttt__));
    printf("u:   %2zu;  u_:   %2zu; u__:     %2zu\n", sizeof(struct u), sizeof(u_), sizeof(u__));
    printf("uuu: %2zu;  uuu_: %2zu; uuu__:   %2zu\n\n", sizeof(struct uuu), sizeof(uuu_), sizeof(uuu__));
    puts("v:   -");//  printf("v:   %2zu;  v_:   %2zu; v__:     %2zu\n", sizeof(struct v), sizeof(v_), sizeof(v__));
    puts("vvv: -\n");//  printf("vvv: %2zu;  vvv_: %2zu; vvv__:   %2zu\n", sizeof(struct vvv), sizeof(vvv_), sizeof(vvv__));
    printf("w:   %2zu;  w_:   %2zu; w__:     %2zu\n", sizeof(struct w), sizeof(w_), sizeof(w__));
    printf("www: %2zu;  www_: %2zu; www__:   %2zu\n\n", sizeof(struct www), sizeof(www_), sizeof(www__));
    printf("x:   %2zu;  x_:   %2zu; x__:     %2zu\n", sizeof(struct x), sizeof(x_), sizeof(x__));
    printf("xxx: %2zu;  xxx_: %2zu; xxx__:   %2zu\n\n", sizeof(struct xxx), sizeof(xxx_), sizeof(xxx__));
    printf("y:   %2zu;  y_:   %2zu; y__:     %2zu\n", sizeof(struct y), sizeof(y_), sizeof(y__));
    puts("yyy: -\n");//  printf("yyy: %2zu;  yyy_: %2zu; yyy__:   %2zu\n\n", sizeof(struct yyy), sizeof(yyy_), sizeof(yyy__));
    printf("z:   %2zu;  z_:   %2zu; z__:     %2zu\n", sizeof(struct z), sizeof(z_), sizeof(z__));
    printf("zzz: %2zu;  zzz_: %2zu; zzz__:   %2zu\n", sizeof(struct zzz), sizeof(zzz_), sizeof(zzz__));

    return 0;
}
```

`cc -Wall -Wextra -o packed packed.c` gives the warnings and errors I commented above.  I had to comment out some code to make it compile.

```
$ ./packed 
s:   24;  s_:   24; s__:     24

t:   24;  t_:   24; t__:     24
ttt: 24;  ttt_: 24; ttt__:   24

u:   10;  u_:   10; u__:     10
uuu: 10;  uuu_: 10; uuu__:   10

v:   -
vvv: -

w:   10;  w_:   10; w__:     10
www: 24;  www_: 24; www__:   24

x:   24;  x_:   24; x__:     24
xxx: 24;  xxx_: 24; xxx__:   24

y:   24;  y_:   24; y__:     24
yyy: -

z:   24;  z_:   24; z__:     24
zzz: 24;  zzz_: 24; zzz__:   24
```

Conclusion:

It only applies to types, and not variables, unlike alignment attributes.  A variable is packed *iff*<sup>[1]</sup> its type is packed.  This makes sense; otherwise a variable could not be assigned to another variable of the same type.

The C2x (C++-style) attribute can only go between the `struct` keyword and the struct tag.

The old GNU-style attribute can go where the C2x one goes, and also after the closing brace.

---

[1]:

```
$ wtf is iff
IFF: if and only if
```